# ORA-01555: Snapshot too old rollback segment with name "" too small error

Tags: oracle, trigger, oracle-11g, tablespaces, blob

I have created a trigger which works on two fields, first field(blob) and second field(varchar2). This trigger updates the blob when there is some changes in second field, from a blob value of another table. While trying to update the table row. It generates an error:

> ORA-01555; Snapshot tool old rollback segment  with name "" too small

I have created a new rollback segment but it could not resolve the error. How can i resolve this issue

this is my trigger:

```
create or replace trigger mytrigger
before update on frarea
for each row
declare 
v_blob blob;

BEGIN
 SELECT VALUE INTO v_blob
from domain_units_backup
where id= :new.category;


:new.echeloncustom := v_blob;

exception

when no_data_found
dbms_output.put_line('no data found');

end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### 01555, 00000, "snapshot too old: rollback segment number %s with name\"%s\" too small"
>
> **Cause:** rollback records needed by a reader for
>   consistent read are overwritten by other writers
>   **Action:** If in Automatic Undo Management mode, increase undo_retention        setting. Otherwise, use larger rollback segments

In Oracle Database while updating the records the old records should be preserved for consistent read purpose. The time period of the preservation can be controlled by the `undo_retention` parameter in databases where Automatic Undo Management is enabled. If the undo retention time is too small then the undo records will be overwritten by other sessions.

Oracle 11g onward, Oracle recommends to use Automatic Undo Management.

> Beginning with Release 11g, automatic undo management is the default mode for a newly installed database.[more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/undo.htm#ADMIN11461)

You can change the undo retention initialization parameter as follow-up

Login as sysdba. Example: Using SQLPLUS in Linux, `$ sqlplus sys as sysdba`.

Then use `ALTER SYSTEM` command as `SQL>alter system set undo_retention=1800`

Undo_retention specifies time in seconds. Before extending undo retention make sure that your undo tablespace is auto extendable and have enough storage to get extended.

Comment: I am new to these things, can you tell me how to use larger rollback segments and increase undo-retention seting.

Comment: @Ahsan Mukhtar: Please notice the edit and all the information regarding undo management as well as whole Oracle administration is well documented , try to follow the Oracle Documentation, specially Oracle Concept Guide as you have said your new to such stuffs. :)